# Java, read an iso image file

Tags: java, iso

I'm developing a java application that needs to read a file contained in a .iso image. 
What Java library do I need to read a file (eg. descriptor.xml) stored on a iso file (eg. C:\myIsoFile.iso)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look to [examples](https://github.com/stephenc/java-iso-tools/blob/master/loop-fs-iso-impl/src/test/java/com/github/stephenc/javaisotools/loopfs/iso9660/Iso9660FileSystemTest.java) in tests of `java-iso-tools`. They are pretty straightforward and easy to follow. Include it into you project as maven dependency.